# Performance impact of session variables

Tags: flask

I am building an application with flask. I would like to know how much data you can store in a session variable without it having to much impact on the performance. For me it could be for instance possible that a list of 200 ID's would need to be stored. What do you guys think?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this but, session data in Flask is limited by the size of the cookie usually 4 KB

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, so you don't think this would have a noticable impact on the performance of my application?

Comment: I think  it is very little impact. In general, storing multiple data in sessions is not something that experts like, because sessions read to memory frequently and instantaneously the better use storing in cache or database